# Testing functions for binary optimization

Tags: optimization, online-resources, binary-programming

It is well known that it is hard to find optimum of some functions, mainly those with lot of local extremes, discontinuities etc. To assess quality of optimization algorithms (particularly heuristics), testing functions suffering from mentioned "deficiencies" have been created. See for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_functions_for_optimization). However, these functions are continuous. Now I am looking for similar library of function or problems connected with binary optimization. I know that binary optimization is generally NP-hard task, however, I would like to test my algorithm on something "very difficult". Could anyone recommend me a suitable resource?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.04425.pdf looks interesting

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Thanks, it is good inspiration.

Comment: https://miplib.zib.de/

Comment: https://biqmac.aau.at/biqmaclib.html